# Automapper nested mapping 3 levels

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper

i have the following problem, i need access to items of sales line from salesheader, when i try access by entity works fine by lazy loading, but i try map with Automapper 6
can´t access to Item from sales header

thanks

```
public class SalesHeader
{
    public int DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostedSalesLine> SalesLines { get; set; }
}
public class SalesLine
{
    public int LineNo { get; set; }
    public int DocumentNo { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
                var result = unitOfWork.SalesHeader.GetById(documenNo);
                Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SalesHeader, SalesHeaderDTO>()

                return Mapper.Map<SalesHeaderDTO>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Done!
Dont use lazy loading, it creates a mess of proxys

```
        public IEnumerable<SalesHeader> GetAllFullDocuments()
    {
        return SalesContext.SalesHeader.Include(sh => sh.SalesLines.Select(i => i.Item))
                                       .Include(sh => sh.SellToCustomer)
                                       .Include(sh => sh.BillToCustomer)
                                       .ToList();
    }
```